# Pagination using jquery append

Tags: php, jquery, twitter, append

I'm trying to implement twitter style pagination, where the user clicks on 'More', resulting in more content appearing.

Current this works fine, however I don't know how to keep track of the current start_limit and end_limit:

```
#  get more replies:
if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] == 'Reply')  
{
   #  yes these will be checked:

   $thread_id = $_POST['id'];
   $start_limit = $_POST['start_limit'];
   $end_limit = $_POST['end_limit'];
   $ajax_auth_token = $_POST['ajax_auth_token'];

   #  return doesn't work?'
   print_r(sql_get_replies_by_thread_id($link, $thread_id, $start_limit, $end_limit));

}
```

The above code basically performs a SQL statement which uses LIMIT $start_limit, $end_limit

This is sent via this code, at the moment I just display the output in an alert box, I know you can use jquery append for the returned HTML:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
               $('.more_replies').live("click",function() {           

            $.post("http://localhost/forum_site/?action=ajax", {id: "40", ajax: "Reply", start_limit: "0", end_limit: "3", ajax_auth_token: "Something" },
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });

               });  
            });
        </script>
```

So the limit will be 0 and 3 (LIMIT 0,3).

How can I get these values from a link e.g. `<a href="/view.php?ajax_auth_token=a&id=x&start_limit=y&end_limit=z">More</a>`

When the user clicks on this link start_limit and end_limit should be incremented by 30.

Comment: I've seen something similar where the limits are added as attributes to the link and then sent down with post and then updated.  i.e. data-start="0" data-end="3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the variables in the `href` attribute then you would have to do some url parsing, reading it extracting the variables and rewriting it. Instead i would suggest you use the jQuery `.data()` method http://api.jquery.com/data/ Then you would something like:

```
//set initial values
$(".more_replies").data("pagination",{start_limit0, end_limit:3});

//then you increment it
var pagination = $(".more_replies").data("pagination");
$(".more_replies").data("pagination",{ 
        start_limit: pagination.start_limit+=30, 
        end_limit: pagination.end_limit+=30, 
});
```